# changing default quantity of magento's grouped product from 0 to 1

Tags: magento-1.9, grouped-products, quantity

For the simple product i can set the minimum quantity of a product from System > Configuration > Inventory > Product Stock Options > Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart , But in grouped product there still it shows the default quantity 0.

I grouped product's default quantity to be 1 instead 0.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit the group product >> on edit page, in the left bar click on “Associated Products” and change the “Default Quantity” values for them.